# SendToBack TlistItemImage at design time or runtime in fireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

In `TlistView` Dynamic appearance I added a few object appearanced to the item.
I have a `TextObjectAppearence` and an `ImageObjectAppearence`.

I want to set the image to be a background for the text meaning the text should be on top of the image.

I tried right-clicking on the image object and selecting `SendToBack` but it doesn't seem to work.

At run-time, there's also not any way to call `ListItemImage.sendtoback` etc.

what is the right way of doing it?

I've attached a screenshot of the two items overlapping...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is to open fmx file in text mode and to move the various objects in the order needed (first is the deeper)

Comment: Thanks! This indeed works. However, I struggle now to get the correct `ItemObject` with the `OnItemClickEx` event. It returns the deepest Item rather than the top.

Comment: That's why  I usually delimit my objects (modifying size and position)  and its alignments to avoid superposition

Comment: But this can't be done if I want to put a background Image